# Adjunction on simplicial sets II

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am trying to understand computation of the adjunction described in [page 245, of Joyals Theory of Quasicategories.](http://mat.uab.cat/~kock/crm/hocat/advanced-course/Quadern45-2.pdf) This is a follow up to my other post.

> Background: $$i^*:S/I \rightarrow S/\partial I = S \times S$$
>
> - $S$ is category of simplicial sets.
> - $I$ is the simplicial set $1 \star 1$, where $1$ is terminal object $\star$ is join operation (explained also in the notes).  $\partial I= 1 \sqcup 1$.
> - $S/I$ is over category. Objects are $X \rightarrow I$, $X \in S$.
> - The construction is as follows, we given $X \rightarrow I$ in $S/I$, we $i^*X$, is the pullback of $X$ along inclusion $\partial I \rightarrow I$.

---

My question: how does one compute,
$$i^* (\Lambda^n_k \rightarrow I)$$

I am hoping there is a simple expression for the pullback. Hopefully of the form of horns and  simplices.

Comment: Note that 1*1 here is just the 1-simplex and the boundary is just two 0-simplices. Taking the product, we should obtain a disjoint union of simplicial sets where one is “the stuff in the horn sent to a vertex” and the other is “the stuff in the horn sent to the other vertex.” This is intentionally vague, but one can actually compute what this is by using the coequalizer formula for the horn. By moving the product into the coequalizer, you can compute this for the (n-1) and (n-2)-simplices and use the coeqaulizer to patch these together.

Comment: Note this is entirely contingent on the structure map to I, and so in general the pullback will vary.